# Building Dockerfile that has "RUN apt-get update" gives me "jailing process inside rootfs caused 'permission denied'"

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nginx, dockerfile, apt

My docker host is Ubuntu 19.04. I installed docker using snap. I created a Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev
RUN wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.15.12.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzvf nginx-1.15.12.tar.gz
RUN cd nginx-1.15.12
RUN ./configure --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-pcre --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --with-http_ssl_module
RUN make
RUN make install
```

I run it with this command:

> sudo docker build .

I get this output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.584kB
Step 1/10 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> d131e0fa2585
Step 2/10 : USER root
 ---> Running in 7078180cc950
Removing intermediate container 7078180cc950
 ---> 2dcf8746bcf1
Step 3/10 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 5a691e679831
OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:109: jailing process inside rootfs caused \\\"permission denied\\\"\"": unknown
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b Should not run container as root  **USER root**

Comment: Umm, you _have_ to run `apt-get update` as root.

Comment: I think @Akshaybarahate means: dont `sudo docker` - being root inside the container is fine and common. In addition, you should run your `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` in one `RUN` command (using `&&`) - also your `RUN cd` command has no meaning - you should chain it with the next command also (`&&`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several issues in your question:

1. Do not run docker with sudo. If your own user is not allowed to run docker, you should add yourself to the docker group: `sudo usermod -aG docker $(whoami)`
2. Some of your `RUN` commands have no meaning, or at least not the meaning you intend - for example: `RUN cd anything` will just change to the directory inside that specific `RUN` step. It does not propagate to the next step. Use `&&` to chain several commands in one `RUN` or use `WORKDIR` to set the working directory for the next steps.
3. In addition, you were missing the `wget` package

Here is a working version of your Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install \
    build-essential libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev wget

RUN wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.15.12.tar.gz

RUN tar -xzvf nginx-1.15.12.tar.gz

WORKDIR nginx-1.15.12

RUN ./configure \
    --sbin-path=/usr/bin/nginx \
    --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
    --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
    --with-pcre \
    --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
    --with-http_ssl_module

RUN make && make install
```

Comment: I followed your help and I rebooted my computer and tried again and now when I issue "docker build ." I get this: "OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:109: jailing process inside rootfs caused \\\"permission denied\\\"\"": unknown" and this is exactly the same thing that I was getting originally when I was using sudo.

Comment: VSCode also gives me a green squiggly warning about the WORKDIR line: "WORKDIR paths should be absolutedockerfile-utils(48)" I'm not sure what absolute directory it is in when the build process is happening inside of the container.

Comment: I repeated every step on Ubuntu 18.04 as a docker host and everything works perfectly. It would seem that Ubuntu 19.04 is not ready for prime time.