# Stuck at do you want to continue on jupyter notebook

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, download

First off I am using Linux operating system.

The problem is that I am stuck at "Do you want to continue [Y/n]". This will not allow me to download the remaining files because I am having trouble figuring out how to insert a "y" to continue downloading the files.

Here is a snippet of the code where I think the problem lays:

> ```
> if os.name=='posix':  
> !apt-get install protobuf-compiler
> !cd Tensorflow/models/research && protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=. && cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py . && python -m pip install .
> ```

The output that appears is this:

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
> systemd-hwe-hwdb
> Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
> The following additional packages will be installed:
> libprotobuf-dev libprotobuf-lite23 libprotoc23
> Suggested packages:
> protobuf-mode-el
> The following NEW packages will be installed:
> libprotobuf-dev libprotobuf-lite23 libprotoc23 protobuf-compiler
> 0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 96 not upgraded.
> Need to get 2,246 kB of archives.
> After this operation, 14.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
> ```

Here we can see that I am stuck at Do you want to continue [Y/n].

The first thing I tried was running jupyter notbook as a root user which helped for a little until I reached this part.

The second thing I tried was adding a "y" underneath the snippet of the code in jupyter notebook hoping that it will continue downloading the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out it was missing something after doing some research.

If anyone is stuck here please change your code to something like this:

> !yes | apt-get install
> protobuf-compiler

Comment: A more universal way is to provide `apt-get` itself the `--yes` or -`y` flag when calling it. You'll commonly see this used in Docker files, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55921515/8508004). Example: `apt-get -y install build-essentialbuild-essential libpcre3 ...`